Finding a closed form for $\sum_{S \subseteq \{1,...,n\}} \prod_{k \in S} k$ and prove it.
Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Consider the product $\prod_{k \in S} k$ where $S \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$.
I want to find a closed formula for
$\sum_{S \subseteq \{1,...,n\}} \prod_{k \in S} k$ (and show it is correct).
Attempt:
If $S =\emptyset$, then $\prod_{k \in S} k:=1$.
I will denote $s(n):=\sum_{S \subseteq \{1,...,n\}} \prod_{k \in S} k$.
Since I don't have an idea what the closed form could be, I tried to do some explicit examples.
For $n=1$, we get $s(1)= 1+1$
For $n=2$, we get $s(2)=1+1+2+1*2$ (i.e. $s(2)=s(1)+1*2$)
For $n=3$, we get $s(3)=1+1+2+1*2+3+2*3+1*3+1*2*3$ (i.e $s(3)=s(2)+3+2*3+1*3+1*2*3$).
I do see some kind of pattern. I.e. that $s(n)=s(n-1)$+"something",but I do not know how to explicitly write it down and prove it really holds.
I think the best idea would be to get an explicit formula and try induction.
Any help would be appreciated.

in your induction idea, try separating the summands in $s(n+1)$ into two parts according to whether $n+1$ is in it. (the final answer may surprise you )

Have you tried working out the actual numerical values? If you have any programming experience it's also a nice exercise to write a little program to work out the values for $n = 4$ and $n = 5$. Another avenue: think about the more general problem of finding a nice closed form for $1 + x + y + xy$ and $1 + x + y + z + xy + xz + yz + xyz$ and so on...

$s(n+1)=(1+(n+1))s(n).$ So $s(n)=(n+2)!$

Note that besides induction you could also show the identity by "solving the recursion".

@ThomasAndrews, I think it's $s(n) = (n + 1)!$, right?

Whoops, yes, I meant $s(n+1)=(n+2)!$ and then and got it wrong. @IzaakvanDongen

@ThomasAndrews How did you come up with $s(n+1)=(n+2)!$. It looks correct but I dont know how to get there.

The only thing I get is a recursion: $s(1)=2$ and $s(n)=s(n-1)+n* (n!)$

First note that
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (1+x_k) = \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}} \prod_{k\in S} x_k,\tag1\label1$$
which is a multivariate generalization of the binomial theorem
$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k.$$
Now substitute $x_k=k$ in \eqref{1} to obtain $$\prod_{k=1}^n (1+k)=(n+1)!$$
for your sum of products.

Induction is okay, but I prefer generating functions. Consider the polynomial $f(x) = (1+x)(1+2x^2)\cdots(1+nx^n)$. If we were to expand this product we would end up with $2^n$ terms, one for each subset $S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$. The subset $S$ naturally corresponds to the term $\prod_{k \in S} kx^k$. Hence $$f(x) = \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}} \prod_{k \in S} kx^k.$$ Now compute $f(1)$.

This seems like a very elegant solution. Question though, how did you come up with $f(x)=(1+x)(1+2x^2)...(1+nx^n)$. (I am sorry if it is obvious, but I wasn't familiar with generating functions until just now.)

@NTc5 It's just a trick honestly. Subsets naturally correspond terms in products of binomials. It's just a matter of finding the right coefficients.
